# How to find view by tag?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `Form` that contains a few `TableLayoutPanel` (List Panels) that I create dynamically.

Each `TableLayoutPanel` has a unique Tag. Actually each panel has `Lable` and this `Lable` has `Name = "lable_name"`

I need to update this exact `Label` inside a `TableLayoutPanel`.

```
public void UpdateLable(string tag, string newText)
        {
            foreach(var tlp in Views)
            {
                if (tlp.Tag.ToString().Equals(tag))
                {
                    var lable = tlp.findViewByName("lable_name") as Label;
                    lable.Text = newText;
                }
            }
        }
```

But I can't find method like `findViewByName()`

So, question is - how to find view by name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a method as below

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> GetControlsOfType<T>(Control control)
{
    var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();
    return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetControlsOfType<T>(ctrl)).Concat(controls).Where(c => c is T);
}
```

Use it like

```
Var control= GetControlsOfType<Label>(yourView).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Tag == tag);

if(control != null)
   control.Text = newText
```

Comment: I did not understand your method, `GetControlsOfType()` take as param `Control`, but the example you write `yourViews` (like an array) is it should be `yourView`? But if it is just one control, so which one? Because actually my question is `how to find one control from among of Controls?`

Comment: Send the instance of the form/control which has all views contained in it

Answer (score 1):

there is no such method directly in `TableLayoutPanel` class. But each `Control` has [Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.controls?view=netframework-4.8) property - collection of child controls.

that specialized collection has [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?view=netframework-4.8) method which allows to get child by name:

```
var label = tlp.Controls.Find("lable_name", true)[0] as Label;
```

Comment: As far as I see method `Find` returns array, so it should be like this `var label = tlp.Controls.Find("lable_name", true)[0] as Label;`, right?